# How to translate string with custom parameters set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have script that write log messages like this:

```
<i18n param1="value1" param2="value2">translation_template</i18n>
```

Parameters amount and names may be various. Message, parameters names and values I gets using regular expression, after that I have data

```
{
    message: 'translation_template'
    param1: 'value1'
    param2: 'value2'
}
```

And I want translate that messages using Ruby on Rails internalization.
Method `i18n.t` can pass parameters and use them in translation:

```
t 'translation_template', param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'
```

If localization file has row

```
some_lang:
  translation_template: "Translated %{param1} is %{param2}"
```

User will see `Translated value1 is value2`

But this syntax implies a certain number of parameters.

How to pass previously unknown parameters set?
For example, via hash, something like this:

```
t 'translation_template', { 'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails internalization already can pass parameters in hash.

But somehow first I could not do it :)

Errors that I have encountered:

- `count` parameter must be integer
- keys must has `Symbol` type

This code works for me:

```
value_params = get_params # get parameters method
translation_params = Hash.new
value_params.each do |param|
    name = param.get_name # get parameter name method
    value = param.get_value # get parameter value method
    value = value.to_i if name == 'count' # convert count value to integer
    translation_params.merge!({name.to_sym => value}) # convert parameter name to Symbol
end
t 'translation_template', translation_params
```